# Regular expression improvement

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write regular expression to capture data, but struggling to finish it.

From the data:

```
Code:Name Another-code:Another name
```

I need to get an array:

```
['Code:Name', 'Another-code:Another name']
```

The problem is that Codes can be almost anything but space.

I know how to do it without using regular expressions, but decided to give them a chance.

**UPDATE:** Forgot to mention that number of elements can vary from one to infinity. So the data:

```
Code:Name -> ['Code:Name']
Code:Name Code:Name Code:Name -> ['Code:Name', 'Code:Name', 'Code:Name']
```

is also suitable.

Comment: Which language are you running? Just split your input according to `\s(?=\S+?:)`

Comment: Will be using JavaScript

Comment: What's the expected output? Why you split your input into two lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just split the input according to the space which is followed by one or more non-space characters and a `:` symbol.

```
> "Code:Name Another-code:Another name".split(/\s(?=\S+?:)/)
[ 'Code:Name', 'Another-code:Another name' ]
```

OR

```
> "Code:Name Another-code:Another name".split(/\s(?=[^\s:]+:)/)
[ 'Code:Name', 'Another-code:Another name' ]
```

Comment: Best solution for multiple occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
^(\S+:.+?)\s(\S+:.+)$
```

`Code:Name` is in group 1 and `Another-code:Another name` in group 2.

`\S+` means one or more character that is not a space.

Comment: Works great on the example provided, but forgot to mention that number of elements can vary. Updated the question

Comment: So it's better to split like @AvinashRaj 's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do this without using regex:

```
var s = 'Code:Name Another-code:Another name';

if ((pos = s.indexOf(' '))>0) 
   console.log('[' + s.substr(0, pos) + '], [' + s.substr(pos+1) + ']');

//=> [Code:Name], [Another-code:Another name]
```